# Ошибка при работе с VK API

Tags: angularjs, vkontakte-api

Делаю запрос, вроде бы все правильно написано, получаю ошибку

```
users.get?user_id=31669992&v=5.60:1 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token :
```

И в теле ошибки получаю данные 
http://joxi.ru/12MWOP7uMlOg1r

Код

```
    $http({
    url: 'https://api.vk.com/method/users.get',
    method: "JSONP",
    params: {
        "user_id": 31669992,
        "v": "5.60"
    }
}).success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
    console.log(data.response);
}).error(function(data, status, headers, config) {
    console.log("error" + data);
});
```

Пример запроса с официальной документации

Вот пример с документации

```
 https://api.vk.com/method/users.get?user_ids=210700286&fields=bdate&v=5.60
```

Comment: Я с Angular не работал, но что-то мне подсказывает, что в параметре method надо записывать имя HTTP-метода (GET или POST), а не формат данных.

Answer (score 0):

Нашел ответ, ошибка была в том, что я не передал в params - callback. Правильно будет вот так

```
        $http({

        url: 'https://api.vk.com/method/users.get',
        method: "JSONP",
        responseType: "json",
        params: {
            callback: "JSON_CALLBACK",
            "user_id": 31669992,
            "v": "5.60"
        }
    }).success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
console.log(data);
    }).error(function(data, status, headers, config) {
        console.log("error" + data);
    });
```